# Machine Learning to output a string based on previous learnt combinations

Tags: machine-learning

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a computer output a string based on previously learned inputs.

For example if I told the machine to learn the following:-

```
toLearn = [
    {input: '12334', output: 'ASDW'},
    {input: '12735', output: 'EDSW'},
    {input: '23725', output: 'RTEF'},
    {input: '75612', output: 'HTEG'},
    etc..
]
```

I know there are 100,000 possible combinations to the above.
If I provided the machine with even 10% of that number, would the machine be able to tell me from what it has learnt that the following would be true?

```
{input: '29847', output: 'FYEW'}
```

Would it also be possible for the machine to provide the correct output just based on the input provided?

```
{input: '29847'}
// output: 'FYEW'
```

If I am barking up the wrong tree with machine learning how would something like this be possible to achieve?

All of the figures above are not true values they are just a representation of what I am trying to achieve. The real model would have around 250,000,000,000 possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine learning can pick out and learn such patterns if they exist in your data. If this is more of a key-value pair mapping with few or no patterns between keys->values, then no, there is no point in using ML.

Comment: How would I go about training to see if there is a pattern within the data?

Comment: I always tell people who first get into ML, plot your data. Encode the y into a numerical expression somehow - e.g. translate chars into ASCII values. Then, before you go to ML, plot x by itself, y by itself, both together. If you see some obvious patterns, ML will pick them out for you too (if done right). If you don't see patterns, it does not mean that they do not exist. You can try clustering on x, y or both together too.